# Is it possible to delete records using a MySQL resource?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from table where id>10");
```

I can delete associated records **using only $res** ?

I mean i do not want make another query like `delete * from table where id>10` so in this way **$res** can be used to get data, and then delete records.

*note :: instead of clicking 'close' to close question, consider understand the question first, is a valid question and not was posted before. :genius:*

Comment: Build a CSV list of your result ID's and use a "delete where in" statement?

Comment: if you are a closeQuestionTroll at least can post an argument as a comment?, the fact you know something doesn't means all others know it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The reason is that the resource you get is for the `mysql_*` PHP extension, and doesn't actually refer to data, a command, or anything on the server.  They are completely separate.  MySQL doesn't care or know how these things are implemented on the MySQL client.

Comment: geez! i am thinking $res was a "reference" to matched records, in this way delete operation would be possible, thanks.

Comment: @iim.hlk, It is in a way.  However, those records haven't been fetched from the server yet.  You need to use `mysql_fetch_*()` for that.  The resource doesn't contain the data, but it does contain enough data for the fetch functions to get that data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the associated records from your query, run a loop on them and delete as needed.  Not sure if that helps with what you're trying to do?

```
<?
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id>10"); 
$rescount = mysql_num_rows($res);
$resloop = 0;

while ($resloop < $rescount){

//do any additional logic here and then add delete statement if desired for the specific record

$resloop++;
}
?>
```

Comment: not looking for this, but thanks ;)